# VBA Insert Into VALUES is reading null for a local variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using Microsoft Access and trying to pull the ID from a table (named Hazards) that has the same ID as the one on a Form (named Edit Hazards). After I pull this value, I want to insert it into another table (named People_Hazards) under Title (Which is an ID as well due to a lookup to another table).

However after I insert it into a local variable, when I try putting it into the insert statement for VALUES, I receive the error message that there are 'Expected parameters 1'.

I have tried using a MsgBox to check if the lookup is correct, and it works fine. But when using the Insert Statement it appears to be receiving nothing for the variable.

I have also triple checked that all my Data Types are correct but even then nothing seems to be working. Any help would be very appreciated! My code is below.

```
Dim x
x = DLookup("[ID]", "Hazards", "[Hazards].[ID] = " & Forms![Edit Hazards]![ID]) 

MsgBox x   'I receive the correct value in the message box here'

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO People_Hazards([Title]) VALUES (x)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its a typo or not but you are inserting `x` as opposed to the `value of x` ,

I recommend making a string first and try to use CurrentDb.Execute on it

```
Dim strSql as string
Dim x as String
x = DLookup("[ID]", "Hazards", "[Hazards].[ID] = " & Forms![Edit Hazards]![ID]) 
strSql="Insert into People_Hazards([Title]) VALUES ("& x & ")"
Msgbox(strSql)
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
```